# moving an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Even though it seems very easy I am unable to do it.

I have an image inside div and I should move the image up and down not the entire div.

**HTML**

```
<div>


<img src="Image/Scope.png" id="indImage" style="height:auto; max-height:80%; width:auto; max-width:90%;" />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $("#moveUp").on('click',function() {

                alert($('#indImage').offset());


                if(wind_moveup_click != 7){
                $('#indImage').animate({
                marginTop : "-=2px"
                });
   });
```

But the image is not moving up

Whats the mistake i am doing?

Thanks:)

Comment: Set the height of your container div to a value higher than the image height and check

Comment: what is "wind_moveup_click "? your code is working with me. i just modify it a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wbNS7/)**

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src="Image/Scope.png" id="indImage" style="height:auto; max-height:80%; width:auto; max-width:90%; position:absolute;" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="moveUp" value="Click Me!" style="margin-top:25px;" />
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#moveUp").on('click', function () {

    //alert($('#indImage').offset());
    var wind_moveup_click = 0;

    if (wind_moveup_click != 7) {
        $('#indImage').animate({
            marginTop: "-=2px"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer has an extra `}` closing the `if` statement, which is what makes this work.

Answer (score 2):

You had forgoten a `}` on your if statement.
You also need to define the `wind_moveup_click` variable before using it in the `if` statement, but maybe you did that, just not in the sample you posted to us.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sAW5w/)**

and this

```
if (wind_moveup_click != 7) {
    $('#indImage').animate({
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:absolute` to your img CSS.

```
#indImage {
    position: absolute;
    height:auto;
    max-height:80%;
    width:auto;
    max-width:90%;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pp2ZR/)

Like @Ohgodwhy correctly said:

> the position can be anything other than static

That means that you can choose between `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed` and so on.

But another **big** problem is that you didn't close the opened `{` in if. So you have a syntax error.

Comment: actually, the position can be anything other than static.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the css style `position: relative` to the `<div>` tag, e.g.:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit as,

```
$('#indImage').animate({
  marginTop : "-2px",
});
```